# XML Serialize large collections of objects to xml

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, out-of-memory

What is the best way to serialize a large collection of objects?
I need to serialize 10 millions of collections from the database to xml.
I always have `OutOfMemoryException`.

Can you help me with it?

Comment: Er... 10 billion registers?? to an XML?? maybe you should reconsider what you are doing and search for another option... In any way, nobody can open a file that big I presume

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in a Read loop one by one. Read one from DB and insert one to XML file by using XmlTextWriter.

Something like below should work for your case.

```
using (var xml = new XmlTextWriter ("filename", Encoding.UTF8))
{
    xml.WriteStartElement ("container_name");

    var cmd = new SqlCommand ("your query", dbConnection);
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader ()) 
    {
        while (reader.Read ()) 
        {
            //
            // Read from DB write to xml
            //

        }

    }

    xml.WriteEndElement (); // Close your container
}
```

[For XmlTextWriter reference check MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx%2a)